# Setting DST timespan on Dell N-series switches that span over newyears

Tags: daylight-saving, dell-powerconnect

I have a stack of brand new Dell N2048 switches. I am doing the initial setup, and am wanting to set up Daylight Savings Time for Australia.

Our DST runs from October to April every year, but the switch will not let me configure this date/time span:

[image: Recurring summer time start values must preceed end values]

> Error: Recurring summer time start values must preceed end values

(which is also spelt incorrectly).

So I thought "Ok, I'll set it from April to October with an offset of -60 minutes, that'll be the same effect" but of course, nope, can't set a negative offset for DST.

Is there any way I can correctly configure DST for these switches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the Dell web GUI. You can set the time span from the CLI with a command like this:

```
clock summer-time recurring 1 sun oct 02:00 1 sun apr 03:00 offset 60
```

This will now reflect correctly in the web interface, but it will not let you modify it.